# How to use flags to append data to file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I have a JavaScript function that writes data to a .json file. Right now, whenever I run the function is deletes or overwrites the existing content on the .json file.

I want to change this so that whenever I run the function new data is appended to the file with the existing data remaining.

I've been reading about Node File System flags (eg `flag: 'a'`) and have been trying to get this working but with no results (the old data is overwritten with the new. No errors occur).

My current function is:

```
function writeFile(obj) {
  var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
  fs.writeFileSync("myData.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', { flag: 'as+' }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log("An error occurred while writing JSON Object to File.");
          return console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log("File updated.");
      }
  });
}
```

I have also tried non synchronous:

```
fs.writeFile("myData.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', { flag: 'a+' }, (err) => {
```

and:

```
await fs.promises.writeFile("pagespeed.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', { flag: 'as+' }, (err) => {
```

But have gotten the same results (no errors, but overwrites not appends).

Would anyone know what I've done wrong or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use [appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsappendfilesyncpath-data-options) for append. BUT appending doesn't make sense for json. Multiple root objects in a json file is not valid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in too many arguments into `fs.writeFileSync` and `fs.writeFile`.

Instead of doing

```js
fs.writeFile("myData.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', { flag: 'as+' }, (err) => { .... });

fs.writeFileSync("myData.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', { flag: 'as+' }, (err) => { .... });
```

do this:

```js
const result = fs.writeFileSync("myData.json", jsonContent, { encoding:'utf8', flag: 'as+' });

// OR

const result = await fs.writeFile("myData.json", jsonContent, { encoding:'utf8', flag: 'as+' });

// OR

fs.writeFile("myData.json", jsonContent, { encoding:'utf8', flag: 'as+' }, (err) => { .... });
```

For more in-depth information see:

[NodeJS Docs | fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback)

[NodeJS Docs | fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options)